# bash, how can I sum the integer values of a column?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I need to find a way to sum up all the integer values of a specific column in a file, and print its result.
This is a piece of my file:

> <<< The program found 0 rare variants for the gene ARIH1 for this
>   HEALTHY_CONTROL <<<
>
> <<< The program found 0 rare variants for the gene ARIH1 for this
>   HEALTHY_CONTROL <<<
>
> <<< The program found 1 rare variants for the gene ARIH1 for this
>   HEALTHY_CONTROL <<<
>
> <<< The program found 0 rare variants for the gene ARIH1 for this
>   HEALTHY_CONTROL <<<
>
> <<< The program found 0 rare variants for the gene ARIH1 for this
>   HEALTHY_CONTROL <<<
>
> <<< The program found 2 rare variants for the gene ARIH1 for this
>   HEALTHY_CONTROL <<<
>
> <<< The program found 0 rare variants for the gene ARIH1 for this
>   HEALTHY_CONTROL <<<
>
> <<< The program found 0 rare variants for the gene ARIH1 for this
>   HEALTHY_CONTROL <<<
>
> <<< The program found 2 rare variants for the gene ARIH1 for this
>   HEALTHY_CONTROL <<<
>
> <<< The program found 0 rare variants for the gene ARIH1 for this
>   HEALTHY_CONTROL <<<
>
> <<< The program found 1 rare variants for the gene ARIH1 for this
>   HEALTHY_CONTROL <<<

I want to print the sum of the 5th column, that is the total number of rare variants.
In this example, it should print 6.

I tried the following command (which did not work):

```
grep "rare variants for the gene ARIH1" fileName | tail -n+2 | awk -F " " '{sum+=$5} END {print sum}'
```

This command prints 1, which is wrong.

How can I do? Thanks!

Comment: `awk '/rare variants for the gene ARIH1/{sum += ($5 + 0)} END{print sum}' filename` should do the job.

Comment: @Davide your script worked when I tried it

Comment: Thanks but they don't work to me... they both generate 1 as a result :-/

Comment: What is the return of `grep "rare variants for the gene ARIH1" fileName | tail -n+2`? and why did you add this part in your question?

Comment: Please show output of `awk '/rare variants for the gene ARIH1/{print $5}' file`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F " " '/<<< The/ {sum += $5} END {print sum}' file
```

The above command should get you the required output.
you may exclude the `-F` switch, since `awk` by default will have space as its delimiter.

Comment: Don't be `root`.

Comment: @tripleee , thanks for the comment. Request you to reach me at `nocut.a@protonmail.com`(e-mail) . Let us discuss regarding this over there.

Comment: What's to discuss? The reasons to not shoot yourself in the foot are well-documented and widely understood.

Comment: I have used online vm , to run that command. That VM had already logged me in as root "https://bellard.org/jslinux/vm.html?url=https://bellard.org/jslinux/buildroot-x86.cfg".

Comment: That's just coincidental, and not something you should include in your answer.

Comment: And I do not understand why are you insisting on not to use root. I understand that remote root logins to the server should be disabled in sshd.conf to have accountability of users who have logged in the server. But what if my server is forwarding the logs to SIEM  Every activity I do will then get captured there. Apart from SIEM , what if I am only allowed to log in through PIM .

Comment: More stuff to ignore in the context of this particular question.

Comment: Yeah , you got it . you shouldn't have said don't be root in your first comment

Answer (score 0):

Try this `awk` script:

```
awk 'BEGIN{sum=0} {if ($0 ~ /rare variants for the gene ARIH1/) sum+=$5} END{ print "Sum is ",sum}' fileName
```

or shorter form of the above script.

```
awk '/rare variants for the gene ARIH1/{sum+=$5} END{print "Sum is ",sum}' fileName
```

Working: It checks whether the following pattern `rare variants for the gene ARIH1` is found in a line (`if ($0 ~ /pattern/)`) . If it's a match then it sums the values in the column 5. At the end, it prints the final sum.